# Long sed script slowing down as it works?

Tags: bash, sed

I run long sed scripts on long files. I've always wanted a progress indicator, and I just learned about pv. Its ETA feature isn't very accurate, but that's not my question. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ cat Crisis.pdf.txt.detagged.tmp | pv -ltea -s 4087 | ./pret2.sed > test.inprocess.tmp
0:17:55 [3.49/s] ETA 0:01:37
```

My question is about the second number. It says 3.49 [lines, because of -l] per second. But it was first 406, and then dropped to around 100, then around 50, and tapered slowly but steadily until it bottomed out about where you see it.

Should I be worried about this, or is expected behavior? Watching my output file with tail, the speed appears to be fairly consistent.

Comment: provide the sed script or anything which produces similar behaviour.

Comment: The sed script is 78,000 lines long. Here's a representative sample...

    #! /bin/sed -f  
  
    ...  
  
    /[a-z]/s/\bDatos\b/·Data·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bdatos\b/·data·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bdañar\b/·hurt·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bDado\b/·Given·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bdado\b/·given·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bDada\b/·Given·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bdada\b/·given·/g  
    /[a-z]/s/\bda\ a\b/·gives·/g

    /[a-z]/s/\bcuyo\b/·whose·/g

    /[a-z]/s/\bcuya\b/·whose·/g

    /[a-z]/s/\bcurar\b/·cure·/g

Comment: doing translation? holy intercourse...

Comment: or make a test file that is half the size and see if you get to only `3.49 * 2/s` speed. My guess is that you'll still end up at `3.49/s` (or close). Good luck.

Comment: I switched units, and measured bits. It also showed slowing, but nowhere near as much. My hypothesis is, being an average, the high numbers are actually not representative. However, that would also indicate that the slowing continues right to the end, because the real speed is slower than the average being shown.

Is it possible this is a memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample line you gave

```
/[a-z]/s/\bDatos\b/·Data·/g
```

I noticed that every line you gave has this

```
/[a-z]/
```

This is not necessary. Every one of your regexes contains `a-z` already, so if it
finds one it will find the other.

Comment: I used that to skips lines in the source document that are either blank or contain only numbers. However, I used it to speed up the process, and it actually slowed it down, though only slightly.